# Get JSON from web API through ASP.NET C#

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json

How to retrieve data from our web api through JSON? This is how our JSON object looks like:

link: `http://localhost:51437/api/values`

```
<ArrayOfMessage xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Entities">
<Message>
<Get_Avsändare>0</Get_Avsändare>
<Get_Datum>2012-12-14 12:12:12</Get_Datum>
<Get_Meddelande>hejsan</Get_Meddelande>
<Get_Mottagare>0</Get_Mottagare>
<Get_Savsändare i:nil="true"/>
<Get_Smottagare>Hanna</Get_Smottagare>
</Message>
<Message>
<Get_Avsändare>0</Get_Avsändare>
<Get_Datum>2012-12-14 12:12:12</Get_Datum>
<Get_Meddelande>svejassa</Get_Meddelande>
<Get_Mottagare>0</Get_Mottagare>
<Get_Savsändare i:nil="true"/>
<Get_Smottagare>Hanna</Get_Smottagare>
</Message>
<Message>
<Get_Avsändare>0</Get_Avsändare>
<Get_Datum>2012-12-14 12:12:12</Get_Datum>
<Get_Meddelande>lalala</Get_Meddelande>
<Get_Mottagare>0</Get_Mottagare>
<Get_Savsändare i:nil="true"/>
<Get_Smottagare>Hanna</Get_Smottagare>
</Message>
<Message>
<Get_Avsändare>0</Get_Avsändare>
<Get_Datum>2012-12-14 12:12:12</Get_Datum>
<Get_Meddelande>hejsan</Get_Meddelande>
<Get_Mottagare>0</Get_Mottagare>
<Get_Savsändare i:nil="true"/>
<Get_Smottagare>Hanna</Get_Smottagare>
</Message>
<Message>
<Get_Avsändare>0</Get_Avsändare>
<Get_Datum>2012-12-14 12:12:12</Get_Datum>
<Get_Meddelande>svejassa</Get_Meddelande>
<Get_Mottagare>0</Get_Mottagare>
<Get_Savsändare i:nil="true"/>
<Get_Smottagare>Hanna</Get_Smottagare>
</Message>
</ArrayOfMessage>
```

this is our JSON call:

```
function Get_5Messages()
{
    $.getJSON(
          'Link',
          function (data) {
              for (var k = 0; k < data.result.length; k++) {
                  $('#div_Meddelande').text("Kontoret nedstängt" + data[i].Get_Meddelande);
              }
          }
    );
    }
```

Comment: That is not JSON, that is XML.

Comment: The "JSON" you put in your question is actually XML, which could be problem number one: You are returning the wrong data type back to the browser. Secondly, the link you posted was to localhost, which is your computer. No one else can view that link but you.

Answer (score 0):

## Hello and welcome to stackoverflow!

**You have shown us an XML document, not a JSON response which would look like the following:**

```
{
    title: "Title data",
    message: "Message data",
    tags: [
        "tag","tag","tag"
    ]
}
```

To parse an xml document *(not really an api)*, you should utilize [jQuery's xml parser](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/)